# How to display other rows in a JTable if one row among them is selected?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am developing hotel reservation application using Swing.

I have a list of rooms in `JTable` rows. If I click any one row then the room that selected goes to a reservation if the user booked that room for particular dates. After that if anyone tries to book the same room for same dates it has to show warning message or how can I hide that row from the table?

```
import javax.swing.*;
/**
 *
 * @author ssn
 */
public class Reservation extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Reservation
     */
    public Reservation() {
        initComponents();
    }
    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        RentPerDay = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        BedType = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        RoomNo = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        RoomType = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel11 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel12 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel13 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel14 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel15 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel16 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel17 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField7 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField8 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField9 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        NoOfdays = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField11 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jComboBox2 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jComboBox3 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel2.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jPanel1.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jLabel2.setText("RESERVATION OF ROOM");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 800, 20));
```

You don't care about the coding, just share me how do the thing

Comment: Okay, what's you problem/question and how is the code you've provided supporting it?

Comment: *"You don't care about the coding.."* I care as much about 'the coding' as you care about a solution. How much do you care about getting an answer? But to correct that slightly, not so much 'the coding' as an MVCE / SSCCE. **For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).** Note that this can be achieved using a [`RowSorter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/RowSorter.html) (which also acts as a **row *filter***).

Comment: i have to clarify more . if i have to hide  a row for that i need to store that record in database? . how will i connect those details into database?

Answer (score 2):

To create listener for row selection in a `JTable` use:

```
yourJTable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(e -> {
     public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
          ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel) e.getSource();
     }
});
```

In this listener you can check if selected room is booked and send it to reservation.

To hide row of `JTable` you should use filtering as explained [in the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting).

Comment: Happy 1K rep. :) That last reputation point you needed was well earned with the suggestion of the method to filter the rows.

Comment: Replace `e ->` with string `new ListSelectionListener()`